# Twitter notifications on ios appears just for selected users. I want the same in Yosemite

Tags: notifications, twitter

In iOs you can setup notifications in order to receive them only from users you activate them for.

Is it possible to achieve the same in Yosemite notification center?

Thanks

Comment: What program do you use?

Comment: usual twitter app

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not see this option in settings of twitter app on Mac.